# Jenkins custom email notifications

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We run several environments within Amazon AWS and have a Jenkins server in each environment. Because we use the EC2 hostnames it's difficult to determine which environment the Jenkins is part of.

Therefore each Jenkins has a file called /etc/environment.txt which contains a environment name (e.g. "DEV4").

Question: How, in the email notifications, can I grab the contents of the file above and set it in the subject line of the email?

Would it be possible to overwrite the template? (I'm yet to find where the template file is..)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have many options:

- Use the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to load a properties file. You need to change the file to become a valid properties file (the contents needs to change to something like `env=DEV4`).
- define a global parameter (manage Jenkins -> configure System)
- define an environment variable on OS level

All three solutions will provide an additional environment variable that can be used within the plugin.

Alternatively, just change the default template of the email notification (needs [email ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)) to contain the env name.